# FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly on project ABP

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor, abp

I downloaded the Volo.Abp.Identity code to make some changes to the package. However, when I import into each project, and run the WEB, the FileNotFound error occurs.

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Volo.Abp.Identity.Application.Contracts, Version=7.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.`

[image]

However, the normal project appears in the bin folder.

I've already imported it into each project, Application.Contracts, HttpApi... All projects.

I put references in all Identity projects, but this error occurs.

What else should I do? In the bin folder, when compiling, the project's dll is being created.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem loading the NuGet package `Volo.Abp.Identity.HttpApi`.

[image: Load error]

Check your console and see your errors.

Sometimes unloading/reloading a project can help resolve the issue.

If that doesn't help, try restarting Visual Studio.

Expected (example):

[image: expected]

(In your case, 7.4.1)